How to disable use of pre-compiled headers for a particular source file
I would like to disable the use of pre-compiled headers for a particular source file.
How to do this with g++ (for MSVC I think I just specify /Y- for that file)
Thanks
David

You can add the preprocessor directive
#undef "PCH_HEADER" 

to the beginning of the file where you don't want to use PCH.
Alternatively, if you are using a makefile, you can create a separate condition to compile without PCH

There is no GCC option to disable the use of a precompiled header,
but there are a couple of ways you can do it.
One way
Per the GCC Manual, 3.22 Using Precompiled Headers:

A precompiled header file can be used only when these conditions apply:



A precompiled header cannot be used once the first C token is seen.


("C token" doubles for "C++ token" here)
So you can disable the use of a precompiled header, say, name.h.gch in the compilation of
file.cpp by ensuring that the translation unit includes some C++ code before it
reaches #include <name.h>.
But you probably know this and don't want modify file.cpp just for the purpose of
disabling the use of name.h.gch - especially if that purpose is short-lived.
Without modifying file.cpp, you can direct the compiler to
pre-include some small innocuous header file in its compilation. Here's
an illustration:
$ tail -n +1 hw.hpp nothing.hpp main.cpp
==> hw.hpp <==
#ifndef HW_HPP
#define HW_HPP
#include <string>

const std::string hw{"Hello World"};

#endif

==> nothing.hpp <==
namespace {}

==> main.cpp <==
#include <hw.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << hw << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Make precompiled header:
$ g++ -c hw.hpp
$ ls *.gch
hw.hpp.gch

Use it normally:
$ g++ main.cpp -I. -save-temps
$ ./a.out 
Hello World

I'm saving the intermediate files (-save-temps) just to show that the pre-compiled header is or is not used.
hw.hpp.gch was used in this case:
$ grep 'hw.hpp.gch' a-main.ii
#pragma GCC pch_preprocess "./hw.hpp.gch"

a-main.ii is the preprocessed text of main.cpp
nothing.hpp is a one-line C++ header file containing some code that compiles to nothing.
Compile like so:
$ $ g++ --include nothing.hpp main.cpp -I. -save-temps
$ ./a.out 
Hello World
  

In this case hw.hpp.gch was not used:
$ grep 'hw.hpp.gch' a-main.ii; echo Done
Done

You could use a temporary file instead of nothing.hpp like:
$ tp=$(mktemp) && echo "namespace {}" > $tp && g++ --include $tp main.cpp -I.

The Other Way
Per the GCC Manual, 3.22 Using Precompiled Headers:

A precompiled header file can be used only when these conditions apply:



Any macros defined before the precompiled header is included must either be defined in the same way as when the precompiled header was generated, or must not affect the precompiled header, which usually means that they don’t appear in the precompiled header at all.


Accordingly, if we make the pre-processing of hw.hpp undefine some arbitrary macro we can disable the use of hw.hpp.gch
in a compilation by defining that macro on the commandline. Here's an illustration.
$ tail -n +1 hw.hpp main.cpp
==> hw.hpp <==
#ifndef HW_HPP
#define HW_HPP
#undef NO_PCH
#include <string>

const std::string hw{"Hello World"};

#endif

==> main.cpp <==
#include <hw.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << hw << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Then:
$ g++ -c hw.hpp # make the `.gch`
$ g++ main.cpp -I. -save-temps
$ ./a.out 
Hello World

The precompiled header is used:
$ grep 'hw.hpp.gch' a-main.ii
#pragma GCC pch_preprocess "./hw.hpp.gch"

But with:
$ g++ -DNO_PCH main.cpp -I. -save-temps
$ ./a.out 
Hello World

it is not used:
$ grep 'hw.hpp.gch' a-main.ii; echo Done
Done

